# facebook application test

Tags: facebook, testing

How can one quickly test facebook application. At the moment I am doing javascript changes and I have to upload every small change on server and refresh it. The application uses FBML.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try [Rell for all your JavaScript needs.](http://apps.facebook.com/fbrelll/)

Secondly, As FBML goes, I'd try opening a test page and using [Static FBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878&b).

As far as I'm concerned, I don't think there is a any way of integrating the two. However, you should check out the [Tools page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools) for some more helpful developer tools.